# use of scala's NodeSeq in lift frame work

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

Can anybody tel about what is the use NodeSeq object in lift frame works form processing.?
can we process our form without using the NodeSeq object.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question - `NodeSeq` is part of scala package `scala.xml.NodeSeq` which offers native support for parsing and working with xml in scala. check the [scala_docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.NodeSeq) for this.

For the second question - Considering NodeSeq is `xml`, you can parse it using an xml parse but as to how to do that... I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

About the second question.

No, not really. The whole idea of Lift is that it deals with HTML templates, transformations and many other stuff. But html templates and transformations are basic and necessary, at least for a non-REST application. And a template *is* an XML, which in terms of Scala is a NodeSeq.

So, if you accept the Lift framework, then you accept that a template is a NodeSeq. BTW, you mainly use it as a class, not an object.

If you have some exact problems with NodeSeq -- you may ask, we'll try to help.